# Logical Biconditional Doubt (Applied to a Case)

Tags: improper-integrals, boolean-algebra

The biconditional logical connective (⇔) produces a value of true if and only if both operands are false or both operands are true. Now, I am studying Calculus II improper integrals. Specifically, the limit comparison test: Be,
$f(x)≥0$ and $g(x)>0$ within $[a;+∞)$. And be $f(x), g(x)$ Riemann integrable functions within $[a;b]$, $∀b≥a$.

And be it,        $$\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{g\left(x\right)}\right)=L$$

Then, if $0<L<∞$

$$\int _a^{+∞}g\left(x\right)dx\:converges\:⇔\int _a^{+∞}f\left(x\right)dx\:converges\:$$

Does that mean that if one of them diverges, then the other is going to diverge as well? It seems intuitively logical to me but I urge to be certain of this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You do understand the biconditional.  (But my spell checker does not.)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) ($\iff$) is a logical connective that is true when both operands are true, or both are false $(0)$, it is false otherwise.

$$(\color{red}{\lnot A}\land\color{red}{\lnot B})\lor(\color{blue}{A}\land \color{blue}{B})\tag{0}$$

The truth table of the biconditional is the following:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&\lnot A&A\\\hline 
\lnot B&\color{red}{1}&0\\
B&0&\color{blue}{1}
\end{array}

The bicontional of two statements is equivalent to the conjunction of two [if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#As_a_truth_function) ($\impliedby$, $\implies$) statements $(1)$, meaning that the truth of the LHS of a biconditional, implies the truth of the RHS.

$$A\iff B \equiv (A\impliedby B)\land(A\implies B)\tag{1}$$

The biconditional can be referred to as *if and only if*, which is often abbreviated to *iff*. In $(1)$, it can be said that the truth of $A$, is a [necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Necessity) and [sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Sufficiency) condition for the truth of $B$, which is another way to refer to the biconditional.

---

In your example, the assertion $(2)$ states that $\int _a^{+∞}g\left(x\right)dx$ will converge if and only if $\int_a^{+\infty}f\left(x\right)dx$ does. Since [divergence is the negation of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85534/not-converging-vs-diverging-improper-integral), $(2)$ also states that the $1^{st}$ integral will diverge iff the $2^{nd}$ does as well.

$$\int _a^{+\infty}g\left(x\right)dx\:\text{converges}\:\iff\int _a^{+ \infty}f\left(x\right)dx\:\text{converges}\:\tag{2}$$